# Calculation of Euclidean distance

Tags: distance

What is the best way to calculate the Euclidean distance between the elements of two point vector layers, without rasterising the layers?

Comment: Using what software package? (edit the question)

Comment: I am curious how you would do it *with* rasterizing the layers!

Comment: I'm _assuming_ [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000) is how he is doing _with_ rasterizng the layers

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to include proof of basic research effort and - if applicable - code so far. Questions requesting code or instructions to copy&paste are generally not well received.

Comment: @GeoGhost I'm serious--I'm not being flippant.  I am not aware of any standard or efficient way of performing this calculation with rasters and would like to be enlightened.

Comment: @whuber - I don't think the Euclidean Distance tool GeoGhost mentioned in Spatial Analyst would work.  Basically, it would convert your two points to a raster with two source cells and everything else as NoData. Then, it would create a new raster with the extent of the two points that calculates the distance from each cell to the closest source cell.  It doesn't calculate the distance between the two points. So, I don't have a clue how you would do that with rasters either.

Comment: I think that this is a misunderstanding based on @Mar's lack of understanding in how the Euclidean Distance tool in ArcGIS works.

Comment: @Baltok Thanks.  There are other possible interpretations of the question, though, that would make a raster-based implementation effective. For instance, if instead of a distance matrix for all pairs of points one wanted only the distances to the *nearest* point in another layer, then extracting values from that layer's Euclidean Distance grid would be a viable solution (and perhaps even a preferred solution when the features are more complicated than points).

Answer (score 1):

Although you provide very little information on this, here is a solution using R.

You can combine the two datasets and use the dist function to calculate a euclidean distance matrix. Here is where some more information would have come in handy. In any method you would end up with a matrix. Is this what you are after or do you want K-nearest neighbor (i.e., your 10 smallest distances for each point observation)? It would also be good to know what you are calculating distance on. Are you wanting euclidean distance on space (coordinates) or covariates? Depending on your actual question you could use spdep or yaImpute as well. If you are using covariates then this is an imputation problem and you want to use yaImpute.

Here is an R function to coerce distance matrices into a data.frame object that, with some additional manipulation, can be joined back to the source data. In the case of using the dist function to return euclidean distance you would just use the dmatrix.df function to coerce to a data.frame. Although, keep in mind that this represents all of the pair-wise distance values and, depending on number of observations, could be a massive matrix. The X1, X2 columns represent the row and column names from the matrix and in this case these are the rownames from the data.frame passed to the dist function. You can figure out how to deal with the pairwise values in the data.frame when you get there.

```
# Matrix to data.frame function
    dmatrix.df <- function(data) {
      varnames=names(dimnames(data))
      values <- as.vector(data)
      dn <- dimnames(data)
        char <- sapply(dn, is.character)
        dn[char] <- lapply(dn[char], type.convert)
      indices <- do.call(expand.grid, dn)
       names(indices) <- varnames
      data.frame(indices, value=values)
    }

    # Create example data and merge data
    n=5 
    x <- data.frame(ID=seq(1,n), x=runif(n,178605,181390), y=runif(n,329714, 333611))
    y <- data.frame(ID=seq(n+1,n+n), x=runif(n,178605,181390), y=runif(n,329714, 333611))
      xy <- rbind(x,y)
        rownames(xy) <- xy$ID

# Calculate distance matrix using x,y columns
( edist <- dist(xy[,2:3]) )

# Create a data.frame object to flatten matrix. 
( edist.df <- dmatrix.df(as.matrix(edist)) )
```